# How to stretch content without changing the size of the views?

Tags: android

I have a layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:gravity="center_horizontal"
              android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:background="@null"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/greeting"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/greeting"
                android:textSize="30sp"/>

            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:text="@string/button1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/button"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>
            <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:text="@string/button2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/button2"
                    android:padding="10dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

How to stretch this four views for the whole height of the screen equidistant from each other, without changing the height of the views themselves? I want to increase the distance between views, rather than the height of them,  when the height of the display inceases.

P.S. Maybe should I look towards `android: layout_gravity = "fill_vertical"`? I tried to use this property, but it didn't help me. Does anyone know exactly how it works?

I'd like to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `LinearLayout` to [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html), define

```
android:layout_rowWeight="1"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
```

on each of the views

[image]